# Flutter-Make button size same

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I want to make the buttons' size the same width using expanded widget.[as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YYuP.jpg)
I want to give some spaces between buttons and make all buttons' sizes the same. I've found some solutions to my question but all of them used the same code as mine. They use expanded widget and make them the same size.

```
Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: kBoxDecoration,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: ReusableCard(
                      label: 'Kiliseler', 
                      onTap: (() {
                        
                      })
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: ReusableCard(
                      label: 'Tüm Detaylı Yapılar', 
                      onTap: (() {
                        
                      })
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: ReusableCard(
                      label: 'Cami, Medrese ve Mescit', 
                      onTap: (() {
                        
                      })
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: ReusableCard(
                      label: 'Sosyal ve Kültürel Tesisler', 
                      onTap: (() {
                        
                      })
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: ReusableCard(
                      label: 'Selatin Camiler', 
                      onTap: (() {
                        
                      })
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: ReusableCard(
                      label: 'Tarihi Çarşılar', 
                      onTap: (() {
                        
                      })
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: ReusableCard(
                      label: 'Dikilitaşlar', 
                      onTap: (() {
                        
                      })
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: ReusableCard(
                      label: 'FSM\'nin Kadırgaları Karadan Yürütme Senaryosu', 
                      onTap: (() {
                        
                      })
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: ReusableCard(
                label: 'Galata Surları', 
                onTap: (() {
                  
                })
              ),
            ),
            IconButton(
              onPressed: (() {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              }), 
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.arrow_circle_left_rounded,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
              iconSize: 75.0,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

```
class ReusableCard extends StatelessWidget {
  
  final String label;
  final VoidCallback? onTap;
  ReusableCard({required this.label, this.onTap});
  
  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[600],
      ),
      onPressed: onTap,
      child: Text(
        label,
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white,
          fontSize: 25.0,
        ),
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Tried to make butons' size same but i couldnt make it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to reduce your text size.
You can try this by updating your ReuseableCard code with this

```
  class ReusableCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final String label;
  final VoidCallback? onTap;
  ReusableCard({required this.label, this.onTap});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: ElevatedButton(
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[600],
        ),
        onPressed: onTap,
        child: FittedBox(
          fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
          child: Text(
            label,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 25.0,
            ),
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```